# What causes "assertion failed: abort=quit, retry=debug, ignore=continue" popups?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, error-handling

I see this popup:

[image]

What causes these errors?

When I attempt to run a unit test.  This popup does not happen except when I run the unit test. I am not trying to test the Microsoft class that is throwing this popup error, so if there is a way to prevent or suppress this error, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a debug version of an assembly. Or you have a Debug.Assert or Debug.Fail somewhere in your code (assuming ProviderManagerBase in your code)

Comment: ProviderManagerBase is a microsoft class. Are you saying that there is a debug.assert somewhere is the GetProvider() method and I am setting it off somehow?

Comment: exactly. I'm also assuming you have a debug version of the assembly. You can quickly verify by opening the method in reflector/ILspy/resharper and taking a look inside